# Xcode 7.3.1 Debug Bar only has two buttons

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I'm just working with Xcode 7.3.1 for the first time, and in the debug bar at the bottom of the screeen there is only two buttons shown.  (A downwards facing arrow/close area button and the breakpoint button/right-facing arrow).

How can I get the full range of buttons that are usually on this bar?

Comment: can you add some images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get full range of buttons which you are expecting unless you execute the app or rather the project which you are working on.

Hope this helps.

Adding a screenshot to confirm:-
[image]

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm talking about.  Thanks for the advice, very helpful